# Transform array in matrix MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, reshape

I have an array matlab very long that I must convert into a matrix.
I have 1440 values (minutes of each day) for every day.
In my simulation I obtain an array of 1440*N, where N is the number of the days.
Now I need to obtain a matrix with N rows and 1440 columns, in order to analyze the data...

I use teh command reshape, but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Would a transpose be sufficient or you need to rearrange your data?

Comment: Why doesn't reshape work? what error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MatA=reshape(ArrayA,N,1440);
```

should work. Did you use `reshape()` in this way?

Comment: I have this error: Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change. This is my command: postureforday=reshape(posture,total_days_simulation,round(length(posture)/total_days_simulation));

Comment: that error means `length(posture)` is not equal `total_days_simulation*round(length(posture)/total_‌​days_simulation)`. This is because your `round()` is altering the number of elements, actualy shouldn't even need it in the first place. Make shure your days of simulation and minutes are consistent

Comment: Use: postureforday=reshape(posture,total_days_simulation,[]);

Comment: Also, I guess you might want to transpose `ArrayA`. So, the final matrix will be `reshape(ArrayA.', N, [])`.